# Computing the homology groups of $S^n \cup_{f} D^{n+1}.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ be a map of degree $m.$ Let  $ X=S^n \cup_{f} D^{n+1}$ be the space attained from $S^n$ by attaching an $(n+1)$-cell via $f.$ Compute homology groups of $X.$

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Using what tools? There is a cell structure with only three cells, and using the cellular boundary formula, there is only one nontrivial map.

Comment: @ElliotG I do not know ..... the question is stated exactly as I mentioned.

Comment: What techniques have been covered in the chapters before? Mayer Vietoris probably, what else?

Comment: @NoelLundström we have covered nearly section I and II of chapter 2

Comment: @ElliotG why using the cellular boundary formula there is only one trivial map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S^n$ has CW structure with a single 0-cell and a single $n$-cell with constant attaching map. Thus $X$ has a CW structure with a single 0-cell and single $n$-cell with constant attaching map, and an $(n+1)$-cell with attaching map $f$ of degree $m$. Cellular homology is probably the fastest way to calculate this (and based on your previous questions I'm assuming you've learned it).

The cellular chain complex is

$$\cdots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{m} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to \cdots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

where we have zero groups in every dimension except $0, n, n+1$.

Assume $m \neq 0$. Calculating the homology of this chain complex we get the homology groups of $X$: $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}, H_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, H_{n+1}(X) \cong 0$ (because multiplication by $m$ is injective) and all other homology groups are necessarily zero.

If $m=0$, then $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}, H_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}, H_{n+1}(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, and all other homology groups are zero.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101466/discussion-on-answer-by-kamills-computing-the-homology-groups-of-sn-cup-f-d).

Comment: I think, in your last line in the solution $H_{n+1}(X)$ should be $\cong$ to 0, am I correct?

Comment: or actually I do not understand why $H_{n+1}(X)$ in the case of $m = 0$ is different from that in the case of $m \neq 0$ .... could you explain this please?